# Fatal error in MPI_Recv: Message truncated, error stack

Tags: c, mpi

I'm  doing a parallel program to multiply two matrices(master-slave) using mpi library, i am getting the error in the title with "Message from rank 0, tag 99 truncated 16 bytes received but buffer size is 0", i figured it crashes when receiving the portion of the matrix at the slaves and when i tried using static 2darrays with const size it worked just fine, so i think the problem is with the n,m,n2,m2 that holds the dimensions of the matrices as when they are predefined it works but when making them as an input the program crashes, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** make_array(int n,int m)
{
    int i,j;
    int **arr = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<m;++i) arr[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter array elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(j=0;j<m;++j) scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    return arr;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

   int processes,rank,workers,rows, extra, offset,i, j, k, **a,**b,**c, n,m,n2,m2, split;

   MPI_Status status;
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&processes);
   if(processes<2){
    printf("Number of processes must be greater than 1 (there are no slaves like this)");
    return 0;
   }
   workers = processes-1;

   if (rank == 0)
   {
      printf("Enter dimensions of first matrix\n");
      scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
      a = make_array(n,m);
      printf("Enter dimensions of second matrix\n");
      scanf("%d %d",&n2,&m2);
      b = make_array(n2,m2);
      if(m!=n2){
        printf("The dimensions of matrices are not suitable for multiplying, exiting .....\n");
        return 0;
      }
      c = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
      for(i = 0;i<m2;++i) c[i] = (int*)malloc(m2*sizeof(int));

      split = n/workers;
      extra = n%workers;
      offset = 0;

      for (i=1; i<=workers; i++)
      {
         rows = (i <= extra) ? split+1 : split;
         printf("Sending %d rows to task %d offset=%d\n",rows,i,offset);
         MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], rows*m, MPI_INT, i, 99,
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         MPI_Send(&b, m*m2, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         offset = offset + rows;
      }

      /* Receive results from worker tasks */

      for (i=1; i<=workers; i++)
      {
          //printf("Heere");

         MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], rows*m2, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 99,
                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         printf("Received results from task %d\n",i);
      }

      /* Print results */
      printf("******************************************************\n");
      printf("Result Matrix:\n");
      for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
         printf("\n");
         for (j=0; j<m2; j++)
            printf("%d  ", c[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n******************************************************\n");
      printf ("Done.\n");
   }

   if (rank > 0)
   {

      MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      MPI_Recv(&a, rows*m, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      MPI_Recv(&b, m*m2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

      for (k=0; k<m2; k++)
         for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
         {
            c[i][k] = 0;
            for (j=0; j<m; j++)
               c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
         }

      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&c, rows*m2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: the second process has a garbage value for m? (apparently in your case it's 0) because only the first process reads it?

Comment: @user253751, thank you that was the issue, after modifying the code and sending the dimensions i get that process 1 caused collective abort of all ranks, do you know what might be the problem? Thanks in advance.